# direction is needed regarding some subjects

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

can someone please help me out finding good tutorials regarding  web-services / ajax / json in .net environment  c# language? preferable video tutorial...that explaining everything from the beginning?

i looked for some and found but they weren't so good ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read some basic tutorial for WCF, and use ASP.NET MVC4 Web API for development.
The two links may help:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/web-service-basics/

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: and what about json? is it ajax only related?

Comment: @slash1z, http://www.json.org/ this is JSON's web site. You can think it as a light-weight XML to represent object. Technically, it has nothing to do with AJAX. AJAX can use JSON or XML or any other format of data, although mostly people use JSON because it is handy.

Answer (score 0):

[100 Best Web Service Tutorial Videos - Meta-Guide.com](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=web%20services%20video%20tutorial&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CE4QFjAE&url=http://www.meta-guide.com/home/about/best-of-the-best-videos/100-best-web-service-videos&ei=HDDQULWBHcqxrAfd9oC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEyVnmfyxrVyn4e9bxcGTbBPoVlPQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk)

[AJAX Videos - ASP.NET AJAX : The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Site](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ajax%20video%20tutorial&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax&ei=WTDQULyEKMmPrgeJoICoCw&usg=AFQjCNG7HG6SOq0qkCp4n4n18td08TM3zg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk)

Comment: and what about json? is it ajax only related?